# Changing text from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, sed, grep

I have ten files text1.html...text10.html. There are numbers 1234567890 in each file. 
How I can change 1234567890 with 0987654321 in each file from the terminal without opening files?

Comment: `grep` is for searching text, not changing them... you can use other tools like `sed` with `-i` option...

Comment: What do  you mean by _without opening files_? Tools will have a hard time changing the content of a file it they can't even look into it or open it for writing.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I mean find the files and change the text from the terminal via script.

Comment: Do you mean that each file contains *literally* `1234567890`, which you want to change to `0987654321`? Or do you mean that each file contains a ten-digit number, like `6095178342`, and you want to reverse it to (for example) `2438715906`? Are the files all exactly one line long? If not, do you want every line processed the same way? Are there any lines that don’t have ten-digit numbers? E.g., are there any numbers with fewer or more than ten digits, and are there any lines with more than one number? Are there any lines with non-numeric data (e.g., letters)?

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
        sed -i 's/1234567890/0987654321/' text$i.html
done
```

**If you're lazy, here it is in a for loop. ;)**

Comment: As written that'll print out the substuted text without saving it anywhere. Perhaps you meant `sed -i.bak 's/1234567890/0987654321/g' text{1..10}.html`

Comment: @roaima So true!  forgot the `-i`

Comment: @AfroJoe why use cycle when you can feed `sed` file mask like in roaima's comment?

Comment: @rush You totally can, and it IS the better solution. :)